# Creating Ordered Query using Meta_key

Tags: posts, wp-query, custom-field, post-meta

I've hit a massive roadblock that I've been stuck on for days now, hope someone can help with this.

The problem:

1. I have a custom field called `order_value` with the values `road`, `air` and `bus`.
2. I am using this custom field to order a set of posts. So all articles belonging to each set of `road`, `air` or `bus` are grouped together and listed. This is being done successfully.
3. Now it looks like `$the_query` is listing the items always in a set alphabetical order of the `meta_value`. For example, 'air, bus, road'. A->Z.
4. I would like for the order to be changed in the query itself so it might order the posts in any sequential order specified, ie. 'Road, Air, Bus' and so on.
5. I am mainly trying to group a set of posts in a specific order that I can specify in the query itself.

Here is my query and what I am trying to do

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    //'cat'       => $term->term_id,
    'meta_key'  => 'order_value',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'meta_value' => array('road','air','bus'),
    'order'      => 'ASC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am trying not to use MySQL query for this as I am not very good at that either.

Comment: I've edited your post to be more readable. I'm in doubt if I've lost something or missed the stream of your thought. Please check it out.
  Also, #3 is difficult to understand. What are you trying to achieve using strange syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sort is either alphabetical or numerical. There is no API way to provide more elaborate sorting rules to the query and messing with SQL for it would be likely impractical.

Since you are retrieving *complete* set of posts (don't have to worry about pagination) the easiest way would be:

1. Request no sort from query.
2. Re–sort `$the_query->posts` set of results with PHP code before starting the loop for output.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Can you give me any sort of direction as to how i can re-sort the array, i've tried to print_r the query to pick up the values, but it looks like meta_values are not in there....

Comment: You would have to retrieve meta for each post for comparison (`get_post_meta()`), it is cached in memory so it won't be bad on resources. Sorting part just gets into territory of pure PHP. :) Inspect data you have `$the_query->posts`, make a plan how you need it arranged, try to express that plan in PHP code.